# Generator polynomial with cyclotomic sets

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, coding-theory

In order to determine the generator polynomial, I should first determine its degree. How do I find the correct degree of generator polynomial $g(x)$ for a cyclic code? The code has length $n = 8$ over $GF(3)$.

I know that $deg(g(x)) = n - k$, with $k$ the dimension, but $k$ is not given.

What I did so far:
$n=8$, $3^{k}$ $($mod $ 8) = 1$. $k$ little as possible $\rightarrow k=2$.
$\beta=\alpha^{(9-1)/8}=\alpha$ with $\alpha$ a primitive element of $GF(9)$:
$\alpha$ root of $x^2+x+2 \rightarrow \alpha^2=1+2\alpha$.

Cyclotomic classes and minimal polynomials:

$C_0=\{0\}\rightarrow 2+x \\
C_1=\{1,3\}\rightarrow 2+x+x^2 \\
C_2=\{2,6\}\rightarrow 1+x^2 \\
C_4=\{4\}\rightarrow 1+x \\
C_5=\{5,7\}\rightarrow 2+2x+x^2 \\
\rightarrow x^8-1=(2+x)(2+x+x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x)(2+2x+x^2)$.

I know the properties of a generator polynomial $g(x)$ but don't know how to apply them to determine the degree.

Comment: Good job so far. Very good actually. You need to know either the dimension or the designed minimum distance of the code to go further. Or, if your boss couldn't give you either, your answer would be a list of possibilities of pairs of those two parameters together with the list of generator polynomials.